# SQL Server -- order by clause is dependent on (field-list, type) pair

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

The query, say "Query-1":

```
select THIS_FIELD, THAT_FIELD, THAT_COUNT 
    from THE_TABLE 
    order by THIS_FIELD
```

is running fine when `THIS_FIELD` is of type `String`. however, "Query-2" below:

```
select THIS_FIELD, THAT_FIELD, THAT_COUNT, * 
    from THE_TABLE 
    order by THIS_FIELD
```

isGiving me an `Ambiguous column name` error to the occurrence of 
`THIS_FIELD` in the select clause when 
`THIS_FIELD` is of type `String`, and is running OK when `THIS_FIELD` here is an integer.

How can i get around this?

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just to make it work. This is non relational.

```
select THIS_FIELD, THAT_FIELD, THAT_COUNT, * 
from THE_TABLE 
order by 1
```

This will work and order by ordinal position.

Answer (score 7):

If the query is as written its likely that you just need an alias on the_table or prefix the columns with the table names so sql knows what to load.

```
select ta.THIS_FIELD, ta.THAT_FIELD, ta.THAT_COUNT, ta.* 
    from THE_TABLE ta
    order by ta.THIS_FIELD
```

Comment: Hmm, this works too. It is interesting what is the difference between aliased and nonaliased version. I see no difference.

Comment: The issue is the *; you are selecting the same column twice and it isn't sure which one to order by.

Comment: this also works-- the one i had in mind-and-didn't-try-out, but it was a quick fix that i was looking for. one that i could use on easy typing during development. shd've mentioned in the Q. thx for the fine ans.